Typing the keys of a predefined object
I have an object like the following:
type Example = { 
  prop: string
}

const example = {
 a: { prop: "a" },
 b: { prop: "b" },
 c: { prop: "c" },
}

example.<hinting; a, b, c>

When I type the object as a record, I lose type hinting because string is too wide:
const example: Record<string, Example> = {
 a: { prop: "a" },
 b: { prop: "b" },
 c: { prop: "c" },
}

example.<no hinting>

How can I restrain the key type to the properties defined in this object in place of Record<string, Example>, without using separate types and helper functions?

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator?

I already read that and don't see how it applies to my situation?

Ok, my mistake, I used satisfies incorrectly - that does indeed solve my issue

If I understand correctly you can do this:
const example = {
 a: { prop: "a" },
 b: { prop: "b" },
 c: { prop: "c" },
} as const satisfies Record<string, Example>


One could leave out the "as const".
